# IE9 does not support css selector >?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-selectors

Well i have the following html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Gallery</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
        <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="Boxes">
                <li>
                    <span>Nature</span>
                </li>
                <li class="Add">
                    <div></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the following css:

```
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
body .Boxes li {
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    background: rgb(27, 161, 226);
}
body .Boxes li.Add div {
    background-position: 0px -352px;
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
    background-image: url("Sprites.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.Boxes {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;

}
.Boxes li {
    margin: 10px; border: 0px currentColor;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Now this works great, but if i change the line "body .Boxes li.Add div {" to "body .Boxes li.Add **>** div {" then it stops working in IE9 and i have no idea why?
Note: it is still working in Opera, Chrome..

Comment: Well, it should: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html BTW: `body .Boxes li` is the same element as `.Boxes li`; why are splitting up your CSS; if you continue that practice, your CSS might become unclear. Try to always use the selector with the lowest possible specificity.

Comment: What has "stopped working"? The css means "select all <div> elements where the parent is a <li> add". And that <div> is empty ...

Comment: @davidkonrad: What does the `div` being empty have to do with the selector?

Comment: The image did not work inside the div tag..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're missing a doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Without it, IE9 will go into quirks mode and in quirks mode, IE won't recognize the `>` selector, among others. This doesn't affect quirks mode in other browsers.